# Python GUI not updating info after program has launched

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

This is what I've written (alot of inspiration from online, since im a student and just started learning python). When I open the program, theres a GUI with one button. When I press the button it displays the time as it should. But if i close the popup window, and press it again, the time is the same as it was last time. In short: I have to re-open the program to display current time (since it does not update with current time after it opens).

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkMessageBox
import datetime



ctime = datetime.datetime.now() .strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
top = tk.Tk()
def showInfo():
    tkMessageBox.showinfo( "Today:", str(ctime))

B = tk.Button(top, text ="Click to show current time", command = showInfo)
B.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkMessageBox
import datetime



top = tk.Tk()
def showInfo():
    ctime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    tkMessageBox.showinfo( "Today:", str(ctime))

B = tk.Button(top, text ="Click to show current time", command = showInfo)
B.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

put `ctime` inside the function `showInfo` to update each time when clicked on the button

Answer (score 0):

You can use a method to get the current time every time you click the button:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkMessageBox
import datetime


def getTime():
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

top = tk.Tk()
def showInfo():
    tkMessageBox.showinfo( "Today:", getTime())

B = tk.Button(top, text ="Click to show current time", command = showInfo)
B.pack()
top.mainloop()
```